# WCF Services An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to create a WCF Service (hosted in a windows service) using **message** security mode with a **custom username** validator.

I have also created a self-signed certificate through IIS.

The problem is that i encounter the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or
>   incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the
>   inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

**WCF Server Configuration:**

```
// Create a WsHttpBinding.
// Set Message Security Mode and UserName Authorization
WSHttpBinding mywshttpbind = new WSHttpBinding();
mywshttpbind.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
mywshttpbind.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
// Negotiate the Credentials and establish a Security Token
mywshttpbind.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
mywshttpbind.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
// Find the BindingElements and disable the TimeStamp
BindingElementCollection elements = mywshttpbind.CreateBindingElements();
elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;

CustomBinding myCustomBinding = new CustomBinding(mywshttpbind);

// A ServiceCertificate will be used - search it by serial number
obj.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "....");
// The client will not check for the certificate
obj.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
// A custom UsernamePassword Validator will be used
obj.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
obj.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustomUserPassValidator();
// Add Endpoint to Host with the custom binding
obj.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(service.IService), myCustomBinding, "");


// Metadata Exchange
ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
serviceBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
obj.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior);

// Open the connection
obj.Open();
```

**WCF Client:**

```
// Create a WsHttpBinding.
// Set Message Security Mode and UserName Authorization
WSHttpBinding mywshttpbind = new WSHttpBinding();
mywshttpbind.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
mywshttpbind.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
// Negotiate the Credentials and establish a Security Token
mywshttpbind.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
mywshttpbind.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
// Find the BindingElements and disable the TimeStamp
BindingElementCollection elements = mywshttpbind.CreateBindingElements();
elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;


CustomBinding myCustomBinding = new CustomBinding(mywshttpbind);


// Create a new factory channel
var newFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICMM_WCF_S>(myCustomBinding, add);

// Set the username and the password
newFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
newFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "user1";
newFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "pass1";


var channel = newFactory.CreateChannel();
channel.get_data();
```

After i enabled the WCF Tracer i traced the following exception:

> The security timestamp is invalid because its creation time
>   ('2015-07-06T10:28:39.264Z') is in the future. Current time is
>   '2015-07-06T10:20:44.570Z' and allowed clock skew is '00:05:00'.

Even i created a Custom Binding with the timestamp disabled the error persists.

Comment: @stuartd: Concerning the possible duplicate:
1) I don't send different credentials - they are the same
2) The development is on the same pc, so there is no time difference.

Comment: So are the timestamps in the request the current time?

Comment: @stuartd: Sorry, i don't understand the question. 
Can you explain a little bit more?
Thanks

Comment: If there are timestamps like [this](https://gist.github.com/stuartd/0ee8a59d74ac8510b41e) in the request, then they must be within 5 minutes of the current time

Comment: @stuartd : I haven't added any timestamps in the config files.
However reading your comments i find another problem. The client will be placed in a pc where i will not have access, so i won't know the time difference. In that case the service will fail. 

So.. what is the fix in situations like these? 
Custom wshttpbinding configurations ?

Comment: The [timestamp element is optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770795/why-is-the-wcf-wshttpbinding-timestamp-optional), but if present must be valid. However you can [change the MaxClockSkew allowed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0e8c30ab-e5a0-40b1-9722-c1b20a09c8ad/maxclockskew-on-wshttpbinding?forum=wcf) in a custom binding.

Comment: @stuartd : You are right, the error is because of the timestamp, but i can't change it even with a custom binding.

Comment: On the other way it worked fine when i changed the MaxClockSkew.
SymmetricSecurityBindingElement security = myCustomBinding.Elements.Find<SymmetricSecurityBindingElement>();
                security.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);